# How to separate one colmn into multiple based on a character vector of delimiters

Tags: r

I have a dataframe which consists of one column. I would like to separate the text into seperate columns based on a vector of delimiters.

***Input:***

```
Mypath<-"Hospital Number 233456 Patient Name: Jonny Begood  DOB: 13/01/77 General Practitioner: Dr De'ath Date of Procedure: 13/01/99 Clinical Details: Dyaphagia and reflux Macroscopic description: 3 pieces of oesophagus, all good biopsies. Histology: These show chronic reflux and other bits n bobs. Diagnosis: Acid reflux likely"
Mypath<-data.frame(Mypath)
names(Mypath)<- "PathReportWhole"
```

***The intended output:***

```
structure(list(PathReportWhole = structure(1L, .Label = "Hospital Number 233456 Patient Name: Jonny Begood\n    DOB: 13/01/77 General Practitioner: Dr De'ath Date of Procedure: 13/01/99 Clinical Details: Dyaphagia and reflux Macroscopic description: 3 pieces of oesophagus, all good biopsies. Histology: These show chronic reflux and other bits n bobs. Diagnosis: Acid reflux likely", class = "factor"), 
    HospitalNumber = " 233456 ", PatientName = " Jonny Begood", 
    DOB = " 13/01/77 ", GeneralPractitioner = NA_character_, 
    Dateofprocedure = NA_character_, ClinicalDetails = " Dyaphagia and reflux ", 
    Macroscopicdescription = " 3 pieces of oesophagus, all good biopsies\n ", 
    Histology = " These show chronic reflux and other bits n bobs\n ", 
    Diagnosis = " Acid reflux likely"), row.names = c(NA, -1L
), .Names = c("PathReportWhole", "HospitalNumber", "PatientName", 
"DOB", "GeneralPractitioner", "Dateofprocedure", "ClinicalDetails", 
"Macroscopicdescription", "Histology", "Diagnosis"), class = "data.frame")
```

I was keen to use the separate function from `tidyr` but can't quite figure it out so that it will separate according to a list of delimiters

The list would be:

```
mywords<-c("Hospital Number","Patient Name","DOB:","General Practitioner:","Date of Procedure:","Clinical Details:","Macroscopic description:","Histology:","Diagnosis:")
```

I then tried:

```
Mypath %>% separate(Mypath, mywords)
```

But I amd clearly mis-understanding the function which I guess can't take a list of delimiters

> ```
> Error: `var` must evaluate to a single number or a column name, not a list
> ```

Is there a simple way of doing this using tidyr (or `csplit` with a list or any other way for that matter)

Comment: Here's a start: `strsplit(as.character(Mypath$PathReportWhole), paste(mywords, collapse = "|"))`

Comment: Is the data always the same format (order) and all parts are included?

Comment: Since you mentioned `cSplit`, here is an idea on that: `setNames(cSplit(transform(Mypath, PathReportWhole = gsub(paste(mywords, collapse = '|'), '-', PathReportWhole)), 'PathReportWhole', '-', 'wide'), c('PathReportWhole' ,mywords))`... Not 100% there but you can work on it a bit

Comment: @docendodiscimus the data is not always in he same order and not all parts are always included but I would hope that it doesn't fail for any row where that is the case- perhaps it just inserts NA into a column. I will test later

Comment: Well that probably makes it a bit more complicated. You can try for the tidyr-way: `Mypath %>% separate(PathReportWhole, into = mywords, sep = paste(mywords, collapse = "|"))` in the meantime.

Comment: @SebastianZeki, Just checking to see whether you tried the suggestion below. Happy to explore another suggestion if it didn't work for you....

Comment: Hi @docendodiscimus can you post as an answer, this seems to work quite well

Comment: Hi @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 in the end I will go with docendo's answer a sit is more compact and seems to do the trick. I've marked yours up though

Comment: @SebastianZeki, please feel free to post that yourself

Answer (score 2):

Maybe make sure that it's like a dcf file, and you can use `read.dcf`:

Notice that "mywords" is a little different from yours. I've added colons to "Hospital Number" and "Patient Name".

```
mywords<-c("Hospital Number:","Patient Name:","DOB:","General Practitioner:",
           "Date of Procedure:","Clinical Details:","Macroscopic description:",
           "Histology:","Diagnosis:")
```

Convert the relevant column to character, add a colon after "Hospital Number".

```
Mypath$PathReportWhole <- as.character(Mypath$PathReportWhole)
Mypath$PathReportWhole <- gsub("Hospital Number", "Hospital Number:", Mypath$PathReportWhole)
```

Make it such that each `key: value` pair is on its own line.

```
temp <- gsub(sprintf("(%s)", paste(mywords, collapse = "|")), "\n\\1", Mypath$PathReportWhole)
```

Use `read.dcf` to read it in:

```
out <- read.dcf(textConnection(temp))
```

---

Here's some sample data that makes it easier to see the resulting structure:

```
example <- c("var 1 abc var 2: some, text var 3: 112 var 4: value var 5: even more here",
            "var 1 xyz var 2: more text here var 5: not all values are there")
example <- data.frame(report = example)
example
#                                                                      report
# 1 var 1 abc var 2: some, text var 3: 112 var 4: value var 5: even more here
# 2           var 1 xyz var 2: more text here var 5: not all values are there
```

And, going through the same steps:

```
mywords <- c("var 1:", "var 2:", "var 3:", "var 4:", "var 5:")
temp <- as.character(example$report)
temp <- gsub("var 1", "var 1:", temp)
temp <- gsub(sprintf("(%s)", paste(mywords, collapse = "|")), "\n\\1", temp)
read.dcf(textConnection(temp))
#      var 1 var 2            var 3 var 4   var 5                     
# [1,] "abc" "some, text"     "112" "value" "even more here"          
# [2,] "xyz" "more text here" NA    NA      "not all values are there"

read.dcf(textConnection(temp), fields = c("var 1", "var 3", "var 5"))
#      var 1 var 3 var 5                     
# [1,] "abc" "112" "even more here"          
# [2,] "xyz" NA    "not all values are there"
```